Is upanayana must to learn vedic suktas?
Is upanayana ceremony needed or is it must to learn Sri rudram, purusha and Sri suktams.im asking this question especially from the perspective of tantra as there are certain Tantric procedures mixed with these chants and others. Thank you in advance. And if in case of being not from the above three varnas how can I learn it ?
